# Pygame: Line fails to collide with rectangle

Tags: python, line, draw, rect

I am trying to write a program that looks like a radar map. I have a line drawn that rotates 360 degrees, and a "bogey" image on the radar. I'm trying to figure out hot to get a line collide with a rectangle, but I get this error. AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

Basically, my question is how do you get a drawn line to collide with a blitted image?

Thanks.

```
import pygame
import math
from colors import *
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

bkrd = pygame.image.load("radar//radar2.jpg")
bkrdrect = bkrd.get_rect()
bogey = pygame.image.load("radar//bogey2.png")
bogeyrect = bogey.get_rect()


window_size = window_width, window_height = 1101,822
window = pygame.display.set_mode( window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption( "Radar" )


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT + 1, 100)

pygame.key.set_repeat(0,0)
window.blit(bkrd,bkrdrect)          
pygame.display.update()


angle = 0
eta = 0
bogey_one_x = 532
bogey_one_y = 210



def mainloop():
    global angle,eta,bogey_one_x,bogey_one_y
    while True:

        angle +=1
        eta +=1

        bogey_one_x += .05
        bogey_one_y +=.02

        window.blit(bkrd,bkrdrect)
        window.blit(bogey,(bogey_one_x,bogey_one_y))

        radar = (685,413)
        radar_len = 253

        x = radar[0] + math.cos(math.radians(angle)) * radar_len
        y = radar[1] + math.sin(math.radians(angle)) * radar_len

        line = pygame.draw.line(window, (green), radar, (x,y), 1)
        linerect = line.get_rect()

        if linerect.colliderect(bogeyrect):
            print "collide"

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ) or \
            ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and \
            ( event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) ):
                running = False
                pygame.quit()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Since `pygame.draw.line()` returns a `Rect`, it's unclear what you're getting from the `line.get_rect()` call since `Rect`s don't have a `get_rect()` method. Try `if line.colliderect(bogeyrect):`.

Comment: I have tried that also. It does not return any errors, but nothing happens either when they collide.

Comment: Hhmm, a comment in the [documentation for `pygame.draw.line()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#comment_pygame_draw_line) indicates it returns a "bad rect" (and proposes a fix). Returning the wrong rectangle could certainly be the cause of the problem. Print out the `Rect` returned and see if it looks valid.

Comment: P.S. Frankly I don't think that checking for rectangle collisions would work even if you can get it working. That's because the "rectangle" of an angled line can be much larger that the line itself. To solve this problem properly is likely going to require some more involved math testing for multiple line and rectangle-edge intersections.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem. Your first suggestion was correct, but the problem I was still encountering was that I blit the image to a simple x/y coordinate rather than to a rect object. Example, "window.blit(bogey,(bogey_one_x,bogey_one_y))" needed to become, "window.blit(bogey,(bogeyrect))". I could then control the coordinates I wanted the image at by typing, "bogeyrect.top=ypos" and "bogeyrect.left=xpos" where xpos and ypos were the coordinates I wanted the image at.

Comment: You were also correct about the rect of an angled line being larger than the line. Luckily in my case my line is so skinny that it is almost unnoticeable. Thank you for your help!